# How to Calculate average from different ordernumbers mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a table with different order numbers and values.
I want to show every unique order and also calculate the avarage from every unique order.
To show every unique order i have this code.:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>

                <tr>

                    <th>Orders</th>
                    <th>X</th>
                    <th>s</th>
                    <th>Cp</th>
                    <th>CpK High</th>
                    <th>CpK Low</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                include 'database.php';
                $results_per_page = 10; // number of results per page
                $pdo = Database::connect();

                if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
                $start_from = ($page-1) * $results_per_page;

                $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Orders FROM metingen ORDER BY Orders DESC LIMIT $start_from, ".$results_per_page;


                foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'. $row['Orders'] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    }
                    Database::disconnect();
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I do know how to calculate a average in sql with this code.:

```
SELECT AVG(KleurL) AS AverageKleurL FROM metingen;
```

But how do i combine that in one sql so i see every order with the calculated KleurL value?

I search with Google and i thought the sql command union shoud do the trick but i don't know how to use it.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like below?

```
SELECT DISTINCT aa.Orders,
       bb.AverageKleurL
FROM metingen aa
JOIN
  (SELECT AVG(KleurL) AS AverageKleurL
   FROM metingen) AS bb
ORDER BY aa.Orders
```

Or are you looking for this?

```
SELECT Orders,
       AVG(KleurL) AS AverageKleurL
FROM metingen
GROUP BY Orders
ORDER BY Orders
```

Comment: The last one i tryed before, but that one calculates the average of all KleurL and not looking for unique Orders with the right average. The first one i'm trying now but how do i call the columns for reading? Normal i  use $row['Orders']  , how do i call them like this $row['aa.Orders'] ?

Comment: You just use $row['Orders']

Comment: The 2nd SQL is calculating the average for rows with same Orders value.